# problems creating session with facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have updated my facebook api and i'm trying to initiate a session like this,

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'foo foo','foo foo' );
```

I get this error on that line,

```
Fatal error: Class 'facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookSession'not found in /foo/foo/foo/header.php on line 41
```

My file path is correct...

Any ideas?

Here is my full code,

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


// include required files form Facebook SDK

// added in v4.0.5
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookSession;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use facebook\src\Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use facebook\src\Facebook\GraphObject;
use facebook\src\Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'foo foo','foo foo' );

 // login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.wuno.com/sandbox/' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }

} else {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  }

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

  // print profile data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://www.wuno.com/sandbox/actions/fbLogout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
}

echo 'sup dude';
?>
```

Comment: the `use` lines should be `use Facebook\FacebookSession;`

Comment: Thank you tons for answering my question.